# Ruby Sunspot Keyword search with IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, solr, sunspot

Simple question:

I've got two models: `Show` and `Contact`.  What I'd like to do is search for either a `Show#id` or a `Contact#name`. So my models are set up as follows:

```
class Show < ActiveRecord::Base

  searchable do
    text :id
  end
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base

  searchable do
    text :name
  end
 end
```

Then I run searches as follows:

```
Sunspot.search(Contact, Show) do
  keywords(MY_QUERY)
end
```

This works great for finding Contacts by their name, but never works with the `Show#id` field.  Can anyone explain why this is?

Joe

Answer (score -1):

The `id` field is an integer, so you should have `integer :id` in the model.  You need to specify the correct type of database column.  Check out the example at http://sunspot.github.com/.

Comment: Yes, but then I can't do what I wanted which is to include the id for that model in the keywords search.